# Apply same table column widths for separated consecutive tables

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, html-table

I'm trying to get two tables to look like each other with the same size columns. So far I have tried with giving them a fixed size that changed on the bootstrap media queries, but this didn't work that well.

I have also tried to use cols which didn't give them the same column size for some reason.

Here is an image showing how I want them to look:

[image: Image of desired look]

**HTML markup:**

```
<div class="container-fluid services animated fadeIn">
<table class="table services">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Here's the full code and example on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ff1c3gv8/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add empty th and td for the second table too and using `table-layout:fixed` css property for table,we can acheive the desired output.

check the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gt1v1q0u/)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to prepare both tables with the same number of columns (in this case 7, where 6 are used for the data and the last one holds the actions). One table row looks like this (for the other table leave all additional cells empty):

```
<tr>
  <td><a href="#">Klipning</a></td>
  <td>35 minutter</td>
  <td>10 minutter</td>
  <td>Ingen</td>
  <td>389,- kr.</td>
  <td>En lækker klipning med alt...</td>
  <td>
    <span class="pull-right">
      <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-times-circle-o"></i>
    </span>
  </td>
</tr>
```

I've put the actions in one cell and a separate span to pull them to the right.

Then apply concrete cell widths (sum up to 100%) through your custom css:

```
.services td {
  width: 12%;
}

.services td:nth-child(6){
  width:30%;
}

.services td:nth-child(7){
  width:10%;
}
```

See the complete example at http://www.bootply.com/1yK3jiZUkL.